pythonでプロジェクトルートにパスを通す方法
pythonを使う際、プロジェクトルートにパスを通すため、毎回site-package下に.pthファイルを配置しています。
しかし新しいプロジェクトごとにこれを毎回行うのはかなり煩わしいです。
具体的には
/Users/USERNAME/DIRECTORY/PROJECTNAME
というふうにPROJECTNAMEの部分を書き換えた文字列をxxx.pthとしてsite-package下に保存するという工程です。
しかしsite-packageにファイルを追加するというよりももっと簡単な方法は無いでしょうか？

XY問題かも？ こちらの記事の話題が類似・関連しているかも？ sys.path.append() を使わないでください, 設定ファイルを使ったPytestのimportError対策, pytestチートシート そうでなければ、もう少し何のために何をどうしたいのかについての情報をもう少し詳しく追記してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方, スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？

単純に「いったいなんのために『site-package下に.pthファイルを配置する』なんてことやってるの?」という点が第三者に伝わってないのだろうと感じます
